# Close Modal Page from the inside of the Page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a Page which I call via:

```
let profileModal = Modal.create(PopupPage);
this.nav.present(profileModal);
```

How to close this modal page from my PopupPage-component:

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
    template: `
<ion-pane padding="" scroll="false">
    <h2>Login with...</h2>
    <p>Please select one of our social logins. We'll never post anything your name
    <button class="button button-default button-full button-danger" style="background-color: #3b5998;"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</button>
    <button class="button button-default button-full button-danger" style="background-color: #db3236;"><i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google</button>
</ion-pane>`,
    host: {
        "(document: click)": "globalClicked( $event )"
    }
})
export class PopupPage {

    constructor(private elmRef: ElementRef) {}

  globalClicked( event ) {
    if( !this.eventTriggeredInsideHost(event)) alert('NOW');
  }

  eventTriggeredInsideHost( event ) {
    var current = event.target;
    var host = this.elmRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('ion-pane')[0];

    do {
      if ( current === host ) {
        return (true);
      }
      current = current.parentNode;
    } while ( current );

    return (false);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to close the popup, you should add an instance of the `ViewController` class in your `constructor` and then use the `dismiss()` method.

```
import { ..., ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class PopupPage {

 constructor(/* ..., */ viewCtrl: ViewController) { }

 dismiss() {
   // You can send information back to the previous page if you need to
   let data = { 'foo': 'bar' };
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works for me. Do you have an idea how to check, if the popup is open at this moment?

Comment: When do you mean by _at this moment_? Anyway, you could try `console.log(this.viewCtrl)` to see what's inside, maybe there's something that could help you check that...

Comment: Via "(document: click)": "globalClicked( $event )" I catch all click events. If the click is outside of the modal box the modal box should disappear. Of course this is event is already fired when clicking the button to open the modal box. So the box should open and directly disappear.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to use `(document: click): globalClicked( $event )` instead of a few buttons with a `click` event handler to show / hide the modal?

Comment: I want to close the modal popup if the user taps outside of the popup.

Answer (score -3):

Use `navPop` in your button to close the modal like this:

```
<ion-buttons start navPop>
    <button>
        <ion-icon `enter code here`></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-buttons>
```